# Is there a way to migrate from GXT to ExtJS step by step?

Tags: extjs, gwt, gxt

Our project uses GWT 2.0 with GXT. Is there a way to migrate to last version of ExtJS step by step having working functionality in the middle of migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny, just had a client, which moves away from ExtJS to GXT.

It should be possible if you are using a mvp pattern (view delegate). In this case you are able to use GXT in one view and ExtJS in another.